# Am I doing this right? ArrayList searching

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a switch statement that allows you to search for a user in a database. The search is basically just searching for a matching character whether it is numeric or alphabetic. It doesn't seem to be working though, any ideas?

Here is main.java

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer.printWelcome();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    while (keepRunning) {
        Printer.printMenu();
        Printer.printPrompt("Please enter your operation: ");

        String userSelection = keyboard.nextLine();

        switch (userSelection) {
        case "1":
            Database.addPerson(personList);
            break;
        case "2":
            Database.printDatabase(personList);
            break;
        case "3":
            Printer.printSearchPersonTitle();
            String searchFor = keyboard.nextLine();
            Database.findPerson(searchFor);
            break;
        case "4":
            keepRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    Printer.printGoodBye();
    keyboard.close();
}

}
```

Here is Database.java

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Database {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

public Database() {

}

public static void addPerson(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    Printer.printAddPersonTitle();
    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter first name: ");
    String addFirstName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter last Name: ");
    String addLastName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter social Security Number: ");
    String addSocial = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter year of birth: ");
    int addYearBorn = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());

    System.out.printf("\n%s, %s saved!\n", addFirstName, addLastName);
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName(addFirstName);
    person.setLastName(addLastName);
    person.setSocialSecurityNumber(addSocial);
    person.setYearBorn(addYearBorn);
    personList.add(person);
}

public static void printDatabase(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personList) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(), p.getAge());

    }

}

public static ArrayList<Person> findPerson(String searchFor) {
    ArrayList<Person> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : personList) {
        boolean isAMatch = false;

        if (p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        }
        if (p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        }
        if (p.getSocialSecurityNumber().contains(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;
            ;
        } else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))
            if (isAMatch) {

            }
        matches.add(p);
        Printer.printPersonList(matches);
    }
    return matches;

}

 }
```

and here is where printer is doing.

```
public static void printPersonList(ArrayList<Person> personListToPrint) {

    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personListToPrint) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(), p.getAge());

    }
```

Comment: "It doesn't seem to be working though" *What specifically* does not work?

Comment: it doesnt display any thing. So im not sure where its going wrong.... not sure if its not looping right or if its not passing data or what.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be passing personList around everywhere like you are doing  Likely, you are not iterating over the copy of personList you think you are doing.  Since personList is empty, printPersonList is never called.  That is why you get no output.

There is really no reason to have personList in Main.java at all.  As the code is written now, the copy of personList you would work with is:

```
private static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

in Database.java.

I might suggest a little further refactoring, but I think that should be enough to get you some working code.

Answer (score 0):

In the method **findPerson** , the variable **isAMatch** seems did not take effort.

No matter what the value of `isAMatch` is, the list `matches` would always add the object `p`.
So , it may look like this:

```
if (isAMatch) {
     matches.add(p);
}
```

Also , the code `Printer.printPersonList(matches);` should be out of the for loop.

By the way , what's the point??

```
else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))
        if (isAMatch) {

        }
```